# 27 different types of cereals. You are sent a random box out of these 27 six months in a row. Probability that you receive at least one repeated box?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

To rephrase the question:

A certain cereal company makes 27 types of cereal. You are sent a random box out of these 27 six months in a
row. What is the probability that you receive at least one repeated box?

I am having difficulty starting this question. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

Think about the complement. What is the probability all the boxes you receive will be different?

There are $27^{27}$ possibilities for what boxes you will receive in what order.

There are only $27!$ ways to receive all different boxes.

Can you take it from here?